# Theme Usage other than default vscode theme

Tags: javascript, themes

Can we use other theme than default VS Code theme ?
I want to use Dracula Theme but can't find it..

Comment: Follow the instructions posted here: https://draculatheme.com/visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1):

Install using Command Palette

1. Go to View -> Command Palette or press Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Then enter Install Extension
3. Write Dracula Official
4. Select it or press Enter to install

[image]

Source: https://draculatheme.com/visual-studio-code